# How to apply a custom className to StepPositionIcon in material-ui?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to customize a vertical stepper like this:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({

  overrides: {
    MuiStepConnector: {
      lineVertical: {
        minHeight: '',
      }
    },
    MuiStepContent: {
      last: {
        borderLeft: ''
      },
    },
    MuiStepIcon: {
      root: {
        '&$active': {
          color: "#fff",
          boxShadow: "0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14)",
          borderRadius: "100px",
        },
      },
    },
    MuiExpansionPanelSummary: {
      expandIcon: {
        left: 8 * -2,
        transition: 'all .5s ease',
      }
    }
  }
});
```

But I cannot override StepPositionIcon properties like:

```
text: {
    fill: theme.palette.primary.contrastText,
    fontSize: theme.typography.caption.fontSize,
    fontFamily: theme.typography.fontFamily
}
```

I want to apply a custom className to StepPositionIcon but don't know where to apply this change? in Stepper, Step or StepLabel?